# Adding 2 differently sized 2d arrays together

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, addition

I am trying to add two differently sized matrices together. For example, the resultant matrix should be matOne[0][0]+matTwo[0][0]; however, I am having trouble taking into account their different sizes (if there's a missing value, it should be assumed it's a 0).
Here's my code:

```
int[][] go(int[][] matOne, int[][] matTwo) 
{
    int size= Math.max(matOne.length, matTwo.length);
    int[][] matThree= new int [size][];
    int c;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    c= Math.max(matOne[i].length, matTwo[i].length);
      for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            if (matOne[j].length > i) {
                matThree[i][j] += matOne[i][j];
            }
            if (matTwo[j].length > i) {
                matThree[i][j] += matTwo[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return matOne;
}
```

Comment: Note that adding two differently sized matrices is mathematically undefined.  (However, that could be irrelevant to your use-case.)

Answer (score 0):

I see the following bugs in the code:

1. You never allocate the inner arrays. After you get `size`, you correctly create the outer array. After you get `c`, you forget to create the inner array for that row.
2. Right inside the `i` loop, one of `matOne[i]` and `matTwo[i]` is likely to fail eventually, whichever one is shorter.
3. Variable `i` iterates over rows, and variable `j` iterates over columns in a row, which means that the `[i][j]` in the `+=` statements are correct, but that the `matOne[j].length > i` should have been `matOne[i].length > j`. Same for `matTwo`.
4. You return the wrong array.

---

Here is the fixed code, using better variable names:

```java
static int[][] go(int[][] matOne, int[][] matTwo) {
    int rows = Math.max(matOne.length, matTwo.length);
    int[][] matThree = new int [rows][];
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        int cells = Math.max((matOne.length > r ? matOne[r].length : 0),
                             (matTwo.length > r ? matTwo[r].length : 0));
        matThree[r] = new int[cells];
        for (int c = 0; c < cells; c++) {
            if (matOne.length > r && matOne[r].length > c) {
                matThree[r][c] += matOne[r][c];
            }
            if (matTwo.length > r && matTwo[r].length > c) {
                matThree[r][c] += matTwo[r][c];
            }
        }
    }
    return matThree;
}
```

*Test*

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matOne = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
        int[][] matTwo = { { 7, 8 }, { 9, 10 }, { 11, 12 } };
        int[][] matThree = go(matOne, matTwo);
        print(matOne);
        System.out.println("+");
        print(matTwo);
        System.out.println("=");
        print(matThree);
    }
    static void print(int[][] mat) {
        for (int[] row : mat) {
            for (int cell : row)
                System.out.printf(" %2d", cell);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

*Output*

```
  1  2  3
  4  5  6
+
  7  8
  9 10
 11 12
=
  8 10  3
 13 15  6
 11 12
```

---

If you don't want the result to be a jagged array, i.e. you want the result to be a 2D rectangular matrix, change the code as follows:

```java
static int[][] go(int[][] matOne, int[][] matTwo) {
    int rows = Math.max(matOne.length, matTwo.length);
    int cols = 0;
    for (int[] row : matOne)
        cols = Math.max(cols, row.length);
    for (int[] row : matTwo)
        cols = Math.max(cols, row.length);
    int[][] matThree = new int [rows][cols];
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            if (matOne.length > r && matOne[r].length > c) {
                matThree[r][c] += matOne[r][c];
            }
            if (matTwo.length > r && matTwo[r].length > c) {
                matThree[r][c] += matTwo[r][c];
            }
        }
    }
    return matThree;
}
```

*Output*

```
  1  2  3
  4  5  6
+
  7  8
  9 10
 11 12
=
  8 10  3
 13 15  6
 11 12  0
```

Comment: Thank you, and the better variable names help a lot! :)

Comment: @Flourine Yeah, variables names are very important for code readability.

Comment: @Flourine If this answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer, so others can see that the question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score -1):

Just before the inner loop; replace current calculation of 'c' and allocate a row for matThree.

```
c = 0;
if (i < matOne.length)
    c = matOne[i].length;
if (i < matTwo.length && matTwo[i].length > c)
    c = matTwo[i].length;
matThree[i] = new int[c];
```

The code inside the inner loop should be:

```
int elem1 = 0, elem2 = 0;
if (i < matOne.length && j < matOne[i].length)
    elem1 = matOne[i][j];
if (i < matTwo.length && j < matTwo[i].length)
    elem2 = matTwo[i][j];
matThree[i][j] = elem1 + elem2;
```

Firstly, it's necessary to allocate storage for the current row of matThree.

Secondly, you need to check that both row and column are within bounds for each matrix.  For my taste it's clearest to explicitly extract the values, defaulting to zero, thus the variables elem1 and elem2.

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in line `c = Math.max(matOne[i].length, matTwo[i].length)`

Comment: The returned matrix does not have the correct values.